# if condition with using only single variable in php

Tags: php

i want to check two string in if condition equal or not but it is give me return true whats the problem please check my code.

```
$if = "(1 == 2)";
if($if){ 
    echo 'hi';
    }
```

see my code above.. it always return hi.. what i was done wrong please help me.

its return only hi.. i have many condition store in if variable but my first condition not fulfill so i want it now.. please suggest me.

my full code is here..

```
$if = "(1 == 2)";
                    if($location_search != ''){
                        $if .= " && ('."$location_search".' == '."$get_city".')"; 
                    }
                    if($location_state != ''){
                        $if .= " && ('."$location_state".' == '."$get_state".')"; 
                    }
                    if($location_bedrooms != ''){
                        $if .= " && ('."$location_bedrooms".' == '."$get_bedrooms".')"; 
                    }
                    if($location_bathrooms != ''){
                        $if .= ' && ('."$location_bathrooms".' == '."$get_bathrooms".')'; 
                    }
                    if($location_type != ''){
                        $if .= ' && ('."$location_type".' == '."$get_type".')'; 
                    }
                    if($location_status != ''){
                        $if .= " && ('".$location_status."' == '".$get_status."')"; 
                    }
if($if){ 
    echo 'hi';
    }
```

i added this code but always return tru and print hi. please help me.

Comment: You're just creating a string. You can try `eval()` (a very bad idea), or you can just create `$if` as a boolean, and change it along the way if you need it.

Comment: Not empty string will be always true according to type conversion rule in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collect all of your variables in one array and go through it with foreach checking everyone. If one of variables is empty, assign false to your if variable. Will write code later, when will be next to computer.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable $if is a declared as a string due to the double quotes. How about this

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

if ($a == $b) {
    // When $a equals $b
    echo "hi";
} else {
    // When $a doesn't equal $b
```

Comment: i have more condition in one tag so how can i assign in single if. please read my whole code.

Comment: @MilanParekh Where is the 1 and 2 coming from and what are you using it for? The rest of those statements are out of context.

Comment: i am doing like this my first condition  (1 == 1) than concate && to another condition so if condition statement work well as i thought. any suggestion in my code very appericiate

Answer (score 0):

$if is a string, and not null. In PHP this means it's true. I think if you remove the quotes, it should instead evaluate the expression to false.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16929010)

Comment: As I recall, the full code was not actually on the question when it was first asked. All I remember seeing was the first box of code, and that was what I addressed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double quotes here " (1 == 2)"

Comment: This only solves the test case. The rest of the code still won't work. I would also recommend reading the [answer] page (and possibly take the site [tour]).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove quotes (with quotes it's a normal string), but keep in mind that this is bad approach and should not be used like this.

Working code:

```
$if = (1 == 2); // evaluates to true

if($if) {

  // code

}
```